# Why aren't observables in NgRx effects subscribed to?

Tags: angular, rxjs

When using observables in Angular my understanding was that an observable will not run unless it is subscribed to. However, when looking at rxjs effects the code us usually something like this:

```
getProcess$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(ProcessActions.getProcessIdSuccess),
      switchMap((action) =>
        this.processService.getProcess(action.payload).pipe(
          delay(5000),
          map((data: any) => ProcessActions.getProcessSuccess({ payload: data }))
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

No where in the code is there a subscribe() method called which is somewhat confusing to me. How is the code in the inner observable being run without being subscribed to? Thanks.

Comment: It is being subscribed to, but by ngrx. It will look through all instance variables of your effect class and runs subscribe on them

Answer (score 2):

NgRx looks after the subscriptions under the hood. That's why we don't have to figure out when/how to subscribe to the various Observables we use within the library.

As a brief aside, wherever possible (it very often is), strictly avoid subscribing to Observables in your TS. Generally speaking, you want to use the `async` pipe in a template somewhere.